# An elegant solution to weighted marbles out of a bag...

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a problem which is similar to one that has been asked before, but it comes with a twist. For reference, the similar problem is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115106/drawing-marbles-out-of-a-bag) one.

I have 100 marbles in a bag and they come in three different colors: Red, Blue, Green.

There are 95 Red marbles, 4 Blue marbles, and 1 Green marble.

When selecting a marble, *all* marbles of that color are removed from the bag. So if I were to select a red marble, all reds would be removed, and there would be only 4 blue, and 1 green left in the bag. (Essentially you can think of this as there being only 3 marbles, a red weighted 95%, a blue weighted 4%, and a green weighted 1%).

What is the probability that, after two selections, I will have drawn a blue marble?

The straightforward solution to this is to add up the probability of having drawn a blue marble after two selections. So I start with the .04 chance to select it on the first try, then add the probability of selecting Red>Blue:(.95 * .8 = 76% chance), and finally the probability of selecting Green>Blue: (.01*~.04 = .0004).

This gives a probability of selecting a blue after two tries: 76.0404%

So this is all well and good (or maybe its not, let me know), but I was hoping there is a more elegant method. For example, in the similar MathOverflow question linked to above, the answerer showed you could calculate the probability that you get **no blue marbles** after two tries and subtract that from 1 to get the probability of selecting a blue marble. However, because the marbles are weighted, it is not so simple to calculate the probability of drawing no blue marbles out of the bag, especially after n+1 selections. It seems we have do the same tedious process as described above, and add the probabilities of Red>Green and Green>Red to get the 'no blue marbles' probability.

This is all kind of gross because, as we add more colors to the bag of varying weights, the number of calculations to determine probability of selecting 'x' color after 'n' selections becomes unwieldy. Any advice or tips and tricks to whittle down the number of operations on larger sets and deeper queries would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't a simplifcation for this. You get a product for each different order in which each admissible set of colours is removed. There may be a couple more products in the positive count and a couple fewer in the negative count, but the fact remains that with such weightings there's no closed form for the sum of the products, you just have to add them all up.

Comment: Bummer. Thanks for taking the time.